# How to retag question about percentages?

Tags: discussion, retagging

The tag on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658897/finding-percentages-between-several-numbers) is "percentile" which is clearly not correct, but I don't know what else to tag it.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Then that would leave the question tagless.  What tags would be appropriate?

Comment: I think [tag:arithmetic] would be appropriate.  From the wikipedia article for arithmetic: "The basic arithmetic operations are addition, subtraction, multiplication and division, although this subject also includes more advanced operations, such as manipulations of percentages, square roots, exponentiation, and logarithmic functions."

Comment: I thought sure I searched for that one.  Anyway ... it's retagged with that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this specific question:

1. [arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic) would do, since it is about percentages.
2. [algebra-precalculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra-precalculus) would also do, since the work that the author has shown introduced the abstract variable $X$.